# Wordpress plugin help

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

On my wordpress site, I am hoping that I would be able to set up a page that only allows the users to access it if the member is logged in.  I still need the link to be available in the navigation but for it to check if the user is signed in... I have been searching for about an hour and cannot really find anything that fits my criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing your own theme, use the function [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in). You could use this to make it so that the link is only clickable if the user is logged in, or so that the page linked to only shows its content if the user is logged in.

If you are not writing your own theme, there may be a plugin you can use to accomplish this.